# ckan create new user issue

Tags: ckan, system-administration

I installed ckan from source recently. After installation, when I try to make a new admin user by the following command:

```
paster sysadmin add seanh -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
```

I see this at the terminal:

```
User "seanh" not found
Create new user: seanh? [y/n]y
Need name and email of the user.
```

And the command exits. Basically I can't enter the name and email of the user when asked. How can I create a new admin user on ckan from the terminal on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The email address is now mandatory and the command has not been updated yet. You need to specify it like this:

```
paster sysadmin add seanj email="sean@j.com"
```

Comment: I've created a fix for this in ckan to avoid this for others in a future release: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3600